# Calculate TableView height according to Image in Delegate

Tags: qt, qml

I have a `TableView` with the following output:

[image: f2cc7453-140d-42b6-9009-bfe6f00e4b4c-image.png]

```
Item {
    property string picture
    
    //...

    id: root
    Rectangle {
        id: rect
        anchors.fill: parent
        border.width: 1
        border.color: "black"
    }

    Image {
        id: image
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        source: root.picture.length > 0 ? "data:image/png;base64," + root.picture : ""
        fillMode: Image.PreserveAspectFit
        sourceSize.width: rect.width - rect.border.width * 2
        sourceSize.height: rect.height - rect.border.height * 2
    }

    //...
}
```

So I would have expected the `Image` fits in the `Rectangle` but it does not.

The `TableView` looks like this:

```
Item {
    id: root
    
    //...
    
    HorizontalHeaderView {
        id: horizontalHeaderView
        syncView: tableView
        anchors.left: tableView.left
        model: [qsTr("Id"), qsTr("Question"), qsTr("Answer 1"), qsTr(
                "Answer 2"), qsTr("Answer 3"), qsTr("Answer 4"), qsTr(
                "Correct Answer"), qsTr("Picture")]
    }
    TableView {
        id: tableView
        width: parent.width
        height: parent.height - horizontalHeaderView.height
        anchors.top: horizontalHeaderView.bottom
        boundsBehavior: Flickable.StopAtBounds

        reuseItems: true
        clip: true
        property var columnWidths: [60, 220, 220, 220, 220, 220, 100, 140]
        columnWidthProvider: function (column) {
            return columnWidths[column]
        }

        model: questionsProxyModel

        delegate: DelegateChooser {
            id: chooser

            //... More DelegateChoices here for the other columns but not 
            //.. interesting for the issue here
            DelegateChoice {
                column: 7
                delegate: PictureDelegate {
                    id: pictureDelegate
                    width: tableView.columnWidthProvider(column)
                    picture: model.picture
                }
            }
        }
        ScrollBar.vertical: ScrollBar {}
    }
}
```

So in the `TableView` I provide the width to each delegate via `columnWidthProvider` which works fine.

The height is calculated automatically according to the content of the childs. This for example makes sure all the text always fits:

[image: a167dac0-0785-4e24-a37c-499b216aff5f-image.png]

Now how can I take the `heigth` the `Image` in the delegate needs to proper scale into account?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Issue could be fixed by making the `Rectangle` the root of `Image` and using `anchors.fill` instead of `anchors.centerIn`

```
Rectangle {
    property string picture
    
    //...

    color: "transparent"
    border.width: 1
    border.color: "black"
    id: root


    Image {
        id: image

        anchors.fill: parent
        anchors.margins: root.border.width

        source: root.picture.length > 0 ? "data:image/png;base64," + root.picture : ""
        fillMode: Image.PreserveAspectFit
    }

    //...
}
```